# view counter, not quite working

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a view counter for my site, but for some odd reason once it counts the first view it doesn't go up anymore

here is the code

```
$checkViews = "SELECT COUNT (counter) FROM pageViews WHERE chapterID = '".$_GET["chapterNo"]."'";
$result=getQuery($checkViews,$l);
if($result == 0)
{
$viewupdate =  "INSERT INTO pageViews (chapterID, counter) VALUES ('".$_GET["chapterNo"]."', 1)";
$result=getQuery($viewupdate,$l);   
}
else if ($result != 0)
{
$viewUpdate = "UPDATE pageViews SET counter = counter++ WHERE chapterID = '".$_GET["chapterNo"]."'";
$result=getQuery($viewUpdate,$l);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no ++ operator in MySQL like there is in PHP or C++, so increment that counter value with counter = counter + 1.

If you want to make your code more streamlined, consider [UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).  This syntax will insert a new value if the key you supply is unique, and updates if the key is already in use:

```
$viewupdate = "INSERT INTO pageViews (chapterID, counter) VALUES ('".$_GET["chapterNo"]."', 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter + 1";
```

This inserts 1 as the counter value if you're inserting a new counter into the database for  a chapter on its first view, or else increments the counter by one.  You don't have to do any checking or additional queries.

Answer (score 0):

Change `counter++` to `counter+1` in your UPDATE sql.

Also, your queries seem to be open to sql injection..

Comment: You didn't do it right then.  :)  It should be `UPDATE pageViews SET counter = counter+1`.  If that still does not work, you have another problem elsewhere.